# Unable to checkout git submodule path when cloning repo after push

Tags: git, git-submodules

After I push the master and submodule, I try to clone the repository to a new folder in computer from the remote.

When cloning the master, it works successfully.

But when I start cloning the submodule, it shows an error message

> Unable to checkout git submodule path

and fails.

Is there some way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, though unable to clone, I still can use the existing repository to pull, so I backup the newest condition files first and pull again,

After pull I find that the Log/History shows master is pushed succesfully previously,but the submodule's history is still at the date in the past, it means the submodule push I just do didn't work, and the newest modification are all lost.
(I have backup previously so it doesn't lost that much)

I think another clue is that the push order I do seems not correct , I push the master first without pushing the submodule, then push the submodule after.

(posiibly the key point about the problem is abnormal change in the file name .gitmodules but I didn't solve problem at the point, but using the way below)

Though it is  possibly not a good idea, I just use the backup file code and copy/paste to the file in repository, and by this way to recover the file in the repository to the newest condition,

and I push again, commit&push the submodule first, then commit&push the master with the submodule,

and try cloning again, the problem disappear and success.